# Can I generate an Open API 3 Python Flask server?

Tags: python, flask, swagger, openapi

From http://editor.swagger.io/ with **swagger 2.0** I am able to select: **Generate Server-->python-flask** and generate a python server that I can deploy and use.

BUT
When I change to use **OpenAPI v3** by selecting **Edit--> Convert to Open API 3** I now no longer see the option to generate a python flask server.

Is this not implemented or is there another way to do this?

Comment: why vote close?

Comment: This sounds like something to ask [Swagger support](https://swagger.io/support/).

Comment: Seeing as the editor outputs a Flask server using [Connexion](https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with the V2 yaml document embedded and Connexion directly supports V3, you could try to take that and swap out the `swagger_server/swagger/swagger.yaml` file for the V3 version after conversion. And do ask Swagger support as to why their code generator can't do that yet.

Comment: Ah, the `x-swagger-router-controller` entries would have to be copied across.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) instead.

- Download http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/4.0.0-beta3/openapi-generator-cli-4.0.0-beta3.jar
- [Mac/Linux] java -jar openapi-generator-cli-4.0.0-beta3.jar generate -g python-flask-server -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/3_0/petstore.yaml -o /tmp/python-flask
- [Windows] java -jar openapi-generator-cli-4.0.0-beta3.jar generate -g python-flask -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/3_0/petstore.yaml -o C:\temp\python-flask\

Answer (score 1):

Python Flask server generator for OpenAPI 3.0 is now available in Swagger Editor and Swagger Codegen 3.0.9+.

Answer (score 0):

1. install Bash Launcher Script from https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/installation
2. create example.sh file

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   openapi-generator-cli generate \
       -g python-flask \
       -i <your .yaml directory> \
       -o <output directory>
   ```
3. run example.sh